# How to make custom scrollbar that shows highlighted items on the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar, highlight

I am a student (beginner coding level) coding a prototype and I am trying to make a custom scrollbar that shows highlighted markers of selected items on the page, similar to VS. I was wondering if anyone might help me with this or be able to point me to a source that shows examples of how to do this?

We have html, some css and javascript coded. I am a beginner so I have I have tried searching on websites for examples but have found none.

Our Javascript for selecting items:

```
 $('.highlight').click(function () {
    // Get the second class name of the parent li
    var highlightClass = $(this).parent().parent().attr('class').split(' ')[
    var highlightItem = '.' + highlightClass + ' > .menuDiv'
    $(highlightItem).toggleClass('highlight-show')
  })
```

The user should be able to select an icon that highlights that object from a long list of other objects, and then scroll down the page to be able to see all of the objects of the same ID that have been highlighted. There are multiple objects with the same ID on the page, so they would all be highlighted when the user selects one of them.

With the final result, those highlighted objects would show up as 'ticks' on the scrollbar so the user can easily find them on the page. This functionality would be used so that the user can easily find a certain item from a long list of items.

Thank you in advance.